# Python Pandas to_csv() blank values problem - from Windows to Mac/Linux

Tags: python, linux, pandas, line-endings

I have created a set of CSVs using Pandas `to_csv()` method. I am on Windows.

The CSVs are then fed into POST requests that insert the data into a CMS.

However, 2 out of the 15 columns in the CSV are showing up blank after POST request.

My colleague confirms the columns are also blank on her Mac machine.

I've tried optional arguments like `encoding='utf-8'` and `line_terminator='\n'`.

Related problem: I suspect some optional parameter on `to_csv()` would do the trick but testing is tricky since I can't replicate the problem locally... I've Ubuntu + Docker and Ubuntu + VirtualBox but as far as I can see the data is showing up OK.

There are a few SO posts similar - but I can't find a good answer for going From_Windows_to_Mac/Linux

```
# df[df['foo']=='bar'].to_csv('testing-1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
# df[df['foo']=='bar'].to_csv('testing-2.csv', encoding='utf-8', line_terminator='\n')


# df[df['foo']=='bar'].to_csv('testing-3.csv', index=False, encoding='ascii')

df[df['foo']=='bar'].to_csv('testing-4.csv', index=False, encoding='ascii', header=False)
```

Comment: Open the files up in notepad before sending the CSVs via post. Are the 2 columns there or not?

Comment: They are there on my Windows machine.
Apparently, they're not there when opened on a Mac.

Comment: Try creating a csv manually (i.e. 3 rows) in notepad. Does the problem exist? If so, then it seems the issue is with the POST doing some processing of the data.

Comment: I like that idea.

I'm trying ```quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC``` also. Will see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was quotations in CSV b/w Windows and Mac/Linux.
Fixed this by adding `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`

```
import csv
df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', line_terminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```